# Python SMB connect automatically

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, applescript, smb

I have function for connect to Smb drive:

```
SMB_CONN = 'smb://192.168.10.105/Shares'
subprocess.Popen(f'open {SMB_CONN}'.split(' '))
```

But this code calls popup window with saved login, password & connect button.

If I create alias to any Smb folder in MacOs and click to it, Mac connect to Smb drive silently.
How to repeat this functionality in python3?

I assume its possible with subprocess & AppleScript.

Update:

```
smbpath = 'smb://192.168.10.105/Shares'
os.system(f"osascript -e 'mount volume \"{smbpath}\"'")
```

working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
smbpath = 'smb://192.168.10.105/Shares'
os.system(f"osascript -e 'mount volume \"{smbpath}\"'")
```

working.